# How to remove black color shades of popup window in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, popup

I created a small popup window in android app for login form shown in the below image. It has some black shades(mentioned in red line) how to remove this, also how to bring arrow shaped symbol in the popup layout(i.e- some customised designs)
[image]

Comment: you can set background color with the help of android:background="@drawable/background"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can set the background to null by `setBackgroundDrawable(null);` by which the new popup window will be transparent

Comment: It will show fully transparent. I need it in a customised color

Comment: thn you need to increase the size of email and password element.so it will cover full popup window without showing popup window's colour

Answer (score 0):

**how to bring arrow shaped symbol in the popup layout(i.e- some customised designs)**

What I thought is you required some quick action popup. Following link along with source codes will help u.

http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/